# moving image along with the scroll inside a TD or DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table of height > 1000. It has Prev and Next buttons on the first and last TDs respectively. I want the Prev and Next button to be positioned in the middle with respect to the screen. I do not want to use JQuery.

```
TABLE -
_________________________________________
|        |                     |        |
|  TD1   |         TD2         |  TD3   |
|        |                     |        |
|        |                     |        |
|--------|---------------------|--------|-----------------------------
|        |                     |        |             _
|        |                     |        |             |
|        |                     |        |             |
|        |                     |        |             |
|   ##   |                     |   ##   |      Screen view now
|        |                     |        |             |
|        |                     |        |             |
|        |                     |        |             |
|        |                     |        |             _
|--------|---------------------|--------|-----------------------------
|        |                     |        |
|        |                     |        |
|        |                     |        |
|        |                     |        |
-----------------------------------------

Legend : ## - Button
```

Comment: Can you give the <td> a width? Then apply margin: 0 auto; to the button?

Comment: vertical-align: middle

Comment: No, I want the image to self center wrt the screen as I scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set style for button elements:

```
.button {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
}
```

Although buttons won't be exactly in the middle (plus half of height), should look ok

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you wachK!

Answer (score 0):

try using CSS. give each of your buttons a class and adjust their margins. Example:

HTML

```
<div class="btnNext"> button info goes here </div>
<div class="btnPrev"> button info goes here </div>
```

CSS

```
.btnNext
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
}

.btnPrev
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if you got my problem, I want the button to remain fixed to the screen as I scroll down or scroll up.

Comment: Ok im sorry. let me try again: If i understand what you want. it is something like the box on this page: http://ryanfait.com/position-fixed-ie6/ where it stays in place while everything scrolls around it. This should fix your problem. bottom/top can be used to position the button relative to the height of the screen. the 0px that i used would put the button at the bottom. using a value of 50% would keep it completely centered